# How to handle condition over time with Django template tags or Python

Tags: python, django

How would you handle this?

I need to be able to set a condition of **open** or **closed** based on some data I'm getting from a stream gauge every hour.  Very new to python and django so if this is a stupid question please forgive me.

The area associated with the gauge is considered closed when the gauge exceeds 10 ft and reopens when it falls below 8ft.  When an area is closed it must remain closed for 24hrs.  I'd like to be able to set the logic within Django's template tags if possible.  The data is populated into a readings model every hour(current condition) and the stations are another model with the logic to check against (flood stage).

This is what I had before I realized the metrics for considering an area closed where a bit more advanced.

```
<td><a href="{% url 'record_detail' pk=item.data.pk %}"><span   
class="status">{% if item.data.stage_feet >= item.flood_stage %}</span>
<span class="alert label">Closed</span>{% else %}<span class="success 
label">Open</span></a></td>{% endif %}
```

Any help extremely appreciated!!

Models:

```
class Location(models.Model):
    station_code = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    station_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    site_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    flood_stage = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    flood_exit = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

class Measurement(models.Model):
    station = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    stage_feet = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    flow_kcfs = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    msl_feet = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    rain_inches = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    measurement_time = models.DateTimeField()
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    geom = gismodels.PointField()
    objects = gismodels.GeoManager()
```

Comment: I am not sure template tags are the way to go. Can you post your model here? I would think a much better implementation is to set a flag on your model, with a `datetime` stamp. Depending upon your workflow, there could be a couple solutions. One of them might be to use something like Celery (www.celeryproject.org) to run a periodic check to switch the flags.

Comment: I've posted my models.  Thankyou for your comment!! @The Brewmaster

Comment: what is item.data in your template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution would be handled outside of a template tag, with some sort of a flag on the model. This will provide you with the benefit of tying the status directly to the instance so that you will know whether it is `open` or `close` outside the confines of the HTML view. My thoughts would be to do something like this to your models.

```py
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import timedelta

class Location(models.Model):
    ...
    is_closed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    closed_at = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.data.stage_feet >= self.flood_stage:
            self.is_closed = True
            if self.closed_at is None:
                self.closed_at = timezone.now()
        elif self.closed_at and self.closed_at > self.reopen_at:
            self.is_closed = False
            self.closed_at = None
        super(Location, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # If using Python 3, this line can be: super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    @property
    is_opened(self):
        return not self.is_closed

    @property
    def reopen_at(self):
        if self.closed_at is None:
            return None
        else:
            return self.closed_at + timedelta(days=1)
```

What I have done is added two fields. One is a `BooleanField` to be a flag about the status, and the other is a `DateTimeField` to capture the time and handle the opening after 24 hours.

*As a side note, there is an [awesome article](http://blog.kevinastone.com/django-model-descriptors.html) on how to integrate these two fields into one. I don't suggest doing that right now, but DEFINITELY worth looking into. Great idea*

Because you said there is already a process to save the data once an hour, I don't think there is a need to do anything outside of the model. Everything can be handled by the `save()` method.

When the instance is saved, it checks to see if the trigger condition has been met. If it has, it sets the `is_closed` property and stores the `datetime`.

If not, then it checks to see if the amount of time has passed, and resets the flag and condition.

I also added a property `is_opened` for your convenience.

I have not tested this code.